Does the Lorentz Transformation preserve the physical integrity of objects?
As is well known, the Lorentz transformation does not only result in a length contraction of objects, but also in different parts of it transformed to different times according to
$$t'=\gamma (t-\frac{vx}{c^2})$$
where $v$ is the velocity of the object and $x$ the coordinate of a certain part of it.
This means for instance that, in principle, a human being moving fast enough along its length, would have the head of a newborn but the feet of an 80-year old (or vice versa), with the rest of the body having an age somewhere in between.
It is hard to see how such a body could work in practice, considering that all parts of the body have to work together in a certain way, which would hardly be possible in this case. So it seems that one can not assign any physical reality to a Lorentz-transformed object. How else would we have to interpret the Lorentz transformation of an object as a whole? Or does it even matter? Does the question of the physical integrity of the object only make sense in its own rest frame?

This is like asking if the laws of perspective make actual changes to the objects being observed.


This means for instance that, in principle, a human being moving fast enough along its length, would have the head of a newborn but the feet of an 80-year old (or vice versa), with the rest of the body having an age somewhere in between.

This is not correct. A human being has a proper length of 5 or 6 light nanoseconds. So the maximum age difference will be less than 5 or 6 ns. To get the age differences you suggest would require an organism of about 80 light years proper length.
The easy way to see this is to look at the spacetime interval. In order for there to be a reference frame where two events are simultaneous, they must be spacelike separated. So, the condition $$\Delta s^2=-c^2 \Delta t^2+\Delta x^2 >0$$ must hold. This easily gives $|\Delta t| < |\Delta x/c|$. So regardless of the frame used, and regardless of $\gamma$, the time difference will be no more than the length of the object divided by $c$
Edit: The more difficult way to see this is to use the Lorentz transform. In the rest frame of a person of length $L$ let $$h(\tau_h)=[\tau_h,0,0,0]$$ be the worldline of the head and let $$f(\tau_f)=[\tau_f,L,0,0]$$ be the worldline of the foot. I am using units where $c=1$, and the convention that the time coordinate comes first in the four-vector $[t,x,y,z]$. The $\tau_h$ and $\tau_f$ are the proper time for the head and foot respectively, which is the age of the head and foot.
Now, we Lorentz transform these worldlines into the primed frame where the person is moving at velocity $v$ in the $x'$ (head to foot) direction to obtain: $$h'(\tau_h)=\left[\frac{\tau_h}{\sqrt{1-v^2}},-\frac{v \ \tau_h}{\sqrt{1-v^2}},0,0\right]$$ and $$ f'(\tau_f) = \left[ \frac{\tau_f}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}-\frac{v \ L}{\sqrt{1-v^2}},-\frac{v \ \tau_f}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}+\frac{L}{\sqrt{1-v^2}},0,0 \right]$$
Finally, we want to compare the age of the head, $\tau_h$, with the age of the foot, $\tau_f$, at the same time in the primed frame. This is done by setting the first component of the two worldlines (coordinate time in the primed frame) equal to each other: $$ \frac{\tau_h}{\sqrt{1-v^2}} = \frac{\tau_f}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}-\frac{v \ L}{\sqrt{1-v^2}} $$ and solving for $$\Delta \tau = \tau_f - \tau_h = v \ L$$
Since $|v|<c$ we confirm the original inequality for $\Delta x = L$, as expected. The difference in age between the head and the foot can be no more than $|\Delta \tau|<L/c$. But this time it is derived with much more effort and care. Note that $\Delta \tau$, the difference in age between the head and the foot, is not zero except for $v=0$.

It is hard to see how such a body could work in practice, considering that all parts of the body have to work together in a certain way, which would hardly be possible in this case

No multicellular biological processes take place on a 5 ns time scale. So that sort of a difference will not matter for objects defined by their biological functioning.
If you did have some human-sized object with important changes happening on that time scale, then indeed the object would be frame variant in that sense. The relevant time scale is the size of the object divided by the speed of light.

For speeds close to the speed of light, the Lorentz transformation formula I quoted above results in a time difference of $\Delta t = \gamma x/c$ for the transformed time at location $x$ compared to that at the origin. If $\gamma \approx 4\cdot 10^{17}$ this would amount to about $80$ years for $x=2m$

@Thomas you forgot length contraction. $x=2 \mathrm{\ m}$ would be a person with a proper length of $8\ 10^{17}\mathrm{\ m}$

$x=2m$ is the proper length

@Thomas it is not. See my edit where I show the easiest way to derive this. You can also derive it through the Lorentz transform, but it is much more difficult, and I leave that as an exercise for the interested reader.

This seems wrong to me.   Suppose I emerge full blown at time $t=0$ with my feet and head at locations $x=0$ and $x=1$.  Then if you are traveling past me at speed $v$, you will say that my feet were born at time $t'=0$ and my head was born at time $t'=-v/\sqrt{1-v^2}$.  Thus you'll say that my head is older than my feet by an amount of time that is arbitrarily large.   Or am I confused?

@WillO you are ignoring time dilation. The amount of coordinate time may be arbitrarily large, but due to time dilation your head will not be arbitrarily older than your feet. You can solve this most easily with the spacetime interval. If you want to use the Lorentz transform it is much more difficult and you cannot take any shortcuts

Dale:  I think we interpreted the question differently, and I think your interpretation was probably the right one.  You asked "In Bob's frame, can Alice's feet's first birthday party be simultaneous with Alice's head's eightieth birthday party?".   I asked "In Bob's frame, can Alice's feet be one year old simultaneous with her head being eighty years old?"  The answer to that question is yes, though Bob's eighty-year-old head will claim to be far less than eighty years old.

@WillO yes that is indeed what I was asking. More specifically I interpreted the phrases “feet of an 80 year old”, “head of a newborn”, and “age somewhere in between” to all refer to the frame invariant proper time.

Sorry, but I don't see how your answer addresses the point I am trying to make: the Lorentz transformation tells us that two events simultaneous in the unprimed frame are separated by a time $\Delta t' = \gamma x/c$ (for v->c) in the primed frame, and $\gamma$ can get arbitrarily large for v->c for any non-zero value of x.

@Thomas that is not what determines something’s age. What determines something’s age is its proper time.

@Thomas :  I believe my comment above addresses your issue.  (Note that the "Bob" in the final sentence is a typo for "Alice".)

@kdp yes, please put your points in a question so we can get to the bottom of the seeming disagreement between you and Dale, since as things stand everyone else is left confused. Or, at least, I certainly am!

@MarcoOcram No need for another separate question. Having given it more thought and giving Dales comments serious consideration, I concede most of Dale's claims. Apologies for any confusion caused and apologies to Dale too. I have done a complete re-write of my answer that I hope is consistent with Dale's now.

When using Lorenz transformations with $x\neq 0$ it is more difficult to interpret the results. It is true that $$t'=\gamma\left(t - \frac{vx}{c^2}\right) \implies \Delta t' = \frac{\gamma x}{c}$$ when $v \to c$. But applying the transformation for $x$: $$x' = \gamma(x - vt) \implies \Delta x' = \gamma x$$ The huge time difference is not being measured at the same location in the moving frame with respect to the body. So, it is better to use the proper time for the moving frame:
When the moving frame passes by the feet, lets both clocks be zero. When passing by the head, the time interval in the body's frame is time dilated compared with the moving frame. So: $t = \gamma t'$, where $t'$ is the time interval in the moving frame, and $t$ in the body's frame. On the other hand:
$$v = \frac{l}{t} = \frac{l'}{t'}$$
where $l$ is the body length in the body's frame, and $l'$ is the body length in the moving frame. So:
$$t = \gamma t' \implies t = \frac{t'}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{l^2}{c^2t^2}}} \implies t^2 = t'^2 + \frac{l^2}{c^2}$$
The time dilation is very small for the length of a human body as mentioned in the Dale's answer.
Anyway, even in the case of a bigger time dilation (for a very big organism), it doesn't affect its functioning in its own frame. Nothing changes only because there is a moving frame nearby.

Strictly speaking the Lorentz transformation describes changes in measurements, not changes in the physical objects themselves. The distinction is subtle, but crucial. All the Lorentz transfromation tells you is how different observers will measure times and distances. It is agnostic as to how, or whether, there are any physical changes involved -- if there are any physical changes, they could just as well be to your instruments as to the object being measured.
Most physicists today subscribe to the view that the Lorentz transformation describes only a coordinate change, and has no more physical significance than rotations or changes of units. "Physical" changes, in this outlook, are those that are agreed upon by all observers. That isn't to say that time dilation or length contraction aren't "real", but their reality lies in changes to how you measure things, not in the things themselves. Using this interpretation, your clocks are measuring different times for the person's head and feet, but that doesn't mean that the person themself has changed (and they would certainly agree that they don't notice any change).

I was not suggesting that the person would notice any changes. My question is whether the person can still be said to exist (having the same physical integrity)  for a moving observer at all, considering that for the latter the Lorentz transformation maps each part of the person's body to a different time.

EDIT: In the interests of intellectual accuracy, and after careful consideration of points raised in the comments and careful re-evaluation of my assumptions, I will concede most of the claims made by Dale and have rewritten this answer accordingly.
I will concede that "Dale's inequality" $|\Delta t| < |\Delta x/c|$, where $|\Delta t|$ is a proper time interval and $|\Delta x|$ is a proper length interval, is in fact correct. The difference in proper aging of body parts is indeed limited by the proper length separation of those body parts.

The above Minkowski spacetime diagram is the rest frame of Eve, who measures Bob to be moving to the right with relative velocity $v=0.8c$. The tilted black lines are the world lines of Bob's feet and head. In this setup, Bob has a proper length of $4 \ \text{light-seconds}$, and Eve measures his coordinate (length contracted) length $\Delta X'$ to be $2.4 \ \text{light-seconds}$. The red diagonal line is a line of simultaneity for Bob. If Bob's feet and head are "time $0$" simultaneously in Bob's rest frame at events $\text{F}$ and $\text{H}$, then Eve will measure a coordinate (time dilated) time difference $\Delta T'$ between those events of $5.33 \ \text{s}$. The proper age of Bob's feet at event $\text{J}$ is $5.33/\gamma = 3.2 \ \text{s}$ and according to Eve at time $\text{D}$ in her reference frame, the proper time of Bob's head is zero. Eve does see a difference in proper ages between Bob's feet and head within the restriction of Dale's inequality. This inequality can be tested in this interactive GeoGebra construction that was used to produce the diagram.

I was not suggesting that the person would notice any changes. My
question is whether the person can still be said to exist (having the
same physical integrity) for a moving observer at all, considering
that for the latter, the Lorentz transformation maps each part of the
person's body to a different time. –  Thomas

You are right that another observer, such as Eve, will calculate Bob to have body parts with different proper ages. This indeed suggests biological consequences for Bob as a functioning biological entity. In the diagram, consider what Eve would measure at a coordinate time midway between her coordinate times of $\text{G}$ and $\text{D}$. From her point of view, Bob's feet would be about $2.66 \ \text{s}$ old, and everything above Bob's waist has not even been born yet! This would indeed be paradoxical. Would we see blood pumping around Bob's legs, even though he does not have a heart yet? It is important to note that in this particular example, Bob is $4 \ \text{light-seconds}$ tall, and this is many orders of magnitude larger than a real person's height, whereas, in reality, the proper time difference would be limited by his height as per Dale. However, for a hypothetical ridiculously long person, this could be problematic, and I think this is the crux of your question. The solution would appear to be that Eve's point of view is just her point of view and effectively an illusion and that Bob's biological functioning is determined by the proper time of his various body parts in the rest frame of his biological system. I notice you use the word "time" without stating whether you mean coordinate or proper time, and it is important to make the distinction.

but also in different parts of it transformed to different times
according to $$t′=γ\left(t−\frac{vx}{c^2}\right)$$

This equation for $t'$ is for the coordinate time measured by Eve, and $t$ is the proper time of the same event measured in Bob's rest frame. To study differences in the age of body parts, what we really need is the difference in proper times. This can derived like the following.
The difference in measured coordinate time ($\Delta t' = t'_2 - t'_1$) is given by:
$$\Delta t' =\frac{t_2 - vx_2/c^2}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}} - \frac{t_1 - vx_1/c^2}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}$$
$$\implies \Delta t' = \frac{(\Delta t-v\Delta x/c^2)}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}$$
$$\implies \Delta t =  \Delta t'\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}+ v\Delta x/c^2.$$
This is the proper time difference between two events separated by a proper spatial distance of $\Delta x$. Notice that for a single clock, such as one attached to Bob's feet that is stationary in Bob's rest frame, $\Delta x = 0$, and the equation agrees with the well-known time dilation formula.
Discussion of the different points of view of Bob & Eve:
Let's say Eve accelerates to some great velocity relative to Bob. She switches off her engines and cruises at a constant velocity. She re-synchronises her clocks because they will have gone out of synchronisation during the acceleration. She will now measure a difference in the proper ages of Bob's feet and head. Eve's acceleration will not have changed anything for Bob. he will not notice any change in his height or any change in biological aging between his feet and head.
Now, let's consider reversing the situation. It is Bob who accelerates this time in a Born rigid manner so that in his reference frame, he considers his height to be constant. Eve, who is watching, sees Bob's feet accelerating faster than Bob's head relative to her reference frame. At any given instant during Bob's acceleration (relative to Eve's reference frame), Bob's feet are moving faster than his head, and so his feet are aging slower than his head from her point of view. This time, Bob does notice something. An accelerometer placed at his feet will register a greater proper acceleration than an accelerometer placed by his head. He will feel like he is being compressed. By the equivalence principle, this situation is equivalent to standing in a strong gravitational field, and he would notice the strong gravitational acceleration on his body. Imagine standing on a neutron star. You would literally be crushed by the strong tidal gravitational forces. If Bob manages to survive and can still function, he would notice clocks by his feet are ticking slower than the clocks by his head while accelerating, just as he would in a strong gravitational field. When he switches off his engine and starts cruising, he will notice another change. He will have to re-synchronise the clocks in his rocket. If it is Bob who accelerates, he will notice many changes, and during the acceleration phase, he will notice a real difference in proper aging of his feet and head, just as he would in a strong gravitational field. Bob would probably not be able to survive the sort of extreme acceleration required to produce the extreme differential aging you are proposing.
When it was Eve who accelerated, the apparent difference in age between Bob's feet and his head that Eve observes is just apparent. The cases of whether it was Bob who accelerates or Eve who accelerates are not symmetrical. When Eve accelerated, it would be she who noticed a difference in proper acceleration measured at her feet and head and a difference in clock rates placed at her feet and head (assuming she is parallel to the $x$-axis and is accelerating in the $x$ direction.). She would notice when she returns to constant inertial motion that it is she who has to re-synchronise her clocks. Eve, somewhere far out in space, suddenly deciding to accelerate does not cause any physical changes to Bob and in this case, Bob notices no difference in clock rates between clocks or accelerometers placed next to his feet and head as a result of Eve accelerating.
A person living on Earth who spends the majority of their life in a vertical position and walks or runs occasionally (which is most people) will have feet that are slightly biologically younger than their head due to gravitational time dilation and SR time dilation because of the back and forward motion of their feet when walking. This is a very tiny effect and probably impossible to measure in practice.

@Dale could you and KDP please get to the bottom of your disagreement, as I don't know which explanation to believe!

@dale and KDP. Hats off to KDP for sorting things out. I think you are both great stack exchangers!

This is essentially Dale's answer, but might be a bit clearer with a picture:

Measure distance in units of "bodylengths" and time in units of "light-bodylengths", so the speed of light is $1$.
Bob travels at velocity $v<1$ with respect to Alice.
The red and blue lines are the worldlines of Alice's feet and head. The dashed black line is Bob's line of simultaneity through the origin. The coordinates of $H$ are $(t=v,x=1)$.  Thus according to Bob, Alice's head is $v$ years older than her feet.
Now $v<1$, where $1$ represents one light-bodylength, i.e. the time it takes light to travel the length of Alice's body.  That's quite a small amount, so according to Bob (and to any other observer) Alice's feet and body are nearly the same age.
Note:  According to Bob at event $H$, the amount of time that has passed since Alice's head emerged from the womb is $v/\sqrt{1-v^2}$, and it has aged by the amount $v$ in the interim.  I am assuming here (as Dale assumed and as I believe the OP intended) that Bob defines the age of Alice's feet to be $v$.  An alternative interpretation is that in this circumstance Bob defines the age of Alice's feet to be $v/\sqrt{1-v^2}$ in which case Bob's account of the age difference between her feet and head can in fact be arbitrarily large.

Can you please explain your note, which is very confusing. I can't understand how Bob can consider Alice to have been born 80 years ago and yet have aged only one nanosecond.

@MarcoOcram : Bob says that all of Alice's clocks, including her biological processes, run slow.

Thanks I understand that but I can’t square it with the rest of your note.

@MarcoOcram: I think I see what's confusing you.  Suppose Alice's head is created at event $G$ in the picture.   In Alice's coordinates, the time difference between events $G$ and $H$ is $v$.  In Bob's coordinates, the time difference between events $G$ and $H$ is $v/\sqrt{1-v^2}$.   In my main answer, Bob defines Alice's head's age at $H$ to be $v$.  In the note, I contemplate that he might alternately define Alice's head's age at $H$ to be $v/\sqrt{1-v^2}$. (CONTINUED)

(CONTINUED)   I meant to illustrate the first possibility with an example in which $v=1$ nanosecond and the second with an example in which $v/\sqrt{1-v^2} =80$ years.   But I made it sound like these are meant to be the same example, which they can't be.  I will fix the wording.

@MarcoOcram :  I hope this makes better sense now.  Thanks for pushing me to fix it.

You are overlooking the fact that the distance x in the formula you cite corresponds to the length of the object in the frame in which it is moving, ie the length after length contraction has been taken into account. That means you cannot get arbitrarily large time differences between the ends of the body, since x decreases as gamma increases.
You should be able to convince yourself of this by considering how length contraction comes about. If you consider the two ends of a body moving through your frame of reference, you are actually considering them at two different points in time in the object's rest frame. Specifically, you are considering the rear of the body slightly later than the front. That means the rear of the body has moved towards the position of the front in the intervening period in the object's rest frame, which causes you to consider the body to be shorter in your frame. For that to work, the time difference between the front and rear of the body has to be short relative to the length and speed of the body. If you take the 80-year difference that you supposed existed in the case of a human body moving at close to the speed of light, the foot of the body would have moved almost 80 light years beyond the position of the head in the time interval, so that rather than having a length-contracted human in your frame you would have one enormously length-dilated and reversed in orientation!
To put it another way, suppose you have some elongated object, such as an enormously long pole, which is simultaneously sprayed with paint all along its length in its rest frame. At the moment the painting is complete, you, in a frame moving at great speed along the length of a pole, trigger an array of cameras to take simultaneous (in your frame) pictures all along the length of the pole. What you are doing is equivalent to taking a set of timelapsed shots all along the pole in its rest frame. You will therefore find that the picture of the leading end of the pole shows it with wet paint, while the subsequent photos taken along the length of the pole show the paint getting successively drier, since in the poles rest frame the picture of the rear end of the pole was taken later than the picture of the front end. If you make a collage of all your photos, it will show the entirety of the pole, seemingly compressed in length, with dry paint at one end and wet paint at the other.

$x$ and $t$ in the transformation formula are the length and time in the reference frame of the object (i.e. the proper length and time), $t'$ the time in the refence frame of the moving observer. This is how the Lorentz transformation is defined.

Try drawing a spacetime diagram- that ought to convince you.

I have added an extra section to my answer which you might find helpful.

The Lorentz transformation applies between inertial frames of reference. When a person walks, it is true that legs are moved quite fast first and with them the rest of the body is carried. However, this occurs under acceleration.
But to answer your question directly, let's say we have three objects linked together in some sense but moving at three different speeds. One of the object can represent the head, the second the body and the third the legs.
Let the velocity of the legs be higher than the body and the velocity of the body higher than that of the head.
Now the faster an object is moving, the more time gets dilated. So from the description given above, the legs would be aging less than the body and the body would be aging less than the head in the inertial frame of reference we have chosen to observe this.
There is nothing wrong with the above.
Now to your questions of practicality. The truth is that when a human being walks they are constantly accelerating and decelerating different parts of their body. Explicitly, they may initially take a step forward with their left leg so it has a higher velocity than the rest of the body, but then when we take the step with the right leg, the left leg is stationary and now has a speed smaller than the rest of the body. The analysis of this problem is not going to be as simple as picking three fixed different Lorentz factors, because in practice the instantenous inertial frames of reference of the body keep changing.
For the problem your described to arise in practice we would need a human being bigger than the solar system. Than if that human were to take a step, its legs could be moving very fast for long enough that they age much less than the head. But I agree such a size human would not be practical and that's why life probably is the size that it is.
Notice that I am saying it has to be very big, because for a usual size human if the legs started moving at relativistic speeds and the head didn't, it wouldn't be practical for very long either.
It could only be sustainable for the life of the human being for a very short instance of time. But after that very short interval, the head and the rest of the body would be once again in the same frame as the legs.
Hope that helps.

It seems you misunderstood my question: I was referring to the scenario of a human flying past you at relativistic speed, and what the Lorentz transformation predicts for this regarding the appearance in the observer's reference.

I don't think the question had anything to do with the relative motion of different body parts.

The formula in the original questions gives us the clock desynchronization based on the $x$ position between two inertial frames.
There is no proper-time delta (time dilation) in the rest frame of the person between the feet and the head because $v=0$ in the rest frame. If the invariance of the space-time interval holds then every inertial observer has to agree there is no time dilation between the feet and the head.
Edit: 2024-08-20
It can be shown by using @Dale's equations proper time spacetime interval calculations.
$h(\tau_h)=[\tau_h,0,0,0]\\
f(\tau_f)=[\tau_f,L,0,0]$
Proper time are clock ticks along a worldline.
If we assume $1s$ ticks they could represent delta/interval between $0,1,2,3,...$
The calculation when $c=1$
$h(3)-h(2)=[3,0,0,0]-[2,0,0,0]$
$\Delta {s_h}^2=-c^2\Delta t^2+\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2+\Delta z^2=-(3-2)^2+0^2+0^2+0^2=-1+0+0+0=-1$
Using metric signature $(-,+,+,+)$ we get time like spacetime interval $\Delta {s_h}^2=-1$.
We assume $L=2/299 792 458m$ for the foot caluclation.
$f(3)-f(2)=[3,2/299 792 458,0,0]-[2,2/299 792 458,0,0]$
$\Delta {s_f}^2=-c^2\Delta t^2+\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2+\Delta z^2\\=-(3-2)^2+(2/299 792 458-2/299 792 458)^2+0^2+0^2=-1+0+0+0=-1$
We conclude there is no proper time delta between the head and the foot in the rest frame. This has to hold in any other moving inertial frame. The calculation will be done for an inertial frame with $v=0.8660254$ where $\gamma =2$.
$h'(\tau_h)={\huge [}\dfrac{\tau_h}{\sqrt{1-v^2}},-\dfrac{v\, \tau_h}{\sqrt{1-v^2}},0,0{\huge ]}$
$h'(3)-h'(2)={\huge [}\dfrac{(3-2)}{\sqrt{1-v^2}},-\dfrac{v\, (3-2)}{\sqrt{1-v^2}},0,0{\huge ]}\\
={\huge [}\dfrac{(3-2)}{\sqrt{1-0.8660254^2}},-\dfrac{0.8660254\, (3-2)}{\sqrt{1-0.8660254^2}},0,0{\huge ]}\\
={\huge [}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-0.75}},-\dfrac{0.8660254}{\sqrt{1-0.75}},0,0{\huge ]}\\
={\huge [}\dfrac{1}{0.5},-\dfrac{0.8660254}{0.5},0,0{\huge ]}\\
={\huge [}2,-1.7320508,0,0{\huge ]}$
$\Delta {s_h'}^2=-c^2\Delta t^2+\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2+\Delta z^2\\=-2^2+(-1.7320508)^2+0^2+0^2=-4+3+0+0=-1$
$\\\\$
$f'(\tau_f)={\huge [}\dfrac{\tau_f}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}-\dfrac{v\,L}{\sqrt{1-v^2}},-\dfrac{v\, \tau_f}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}+\dfrac{L}{\sqrt{1-v^2}},0,0{\huge ]}$
$f'(3)-f'(2)={\huge [}\dfrac{(3-2)}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}-\dfrac{v\,2/299 792 458}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}+\dfrac{v\,2/299 792 458}{\sqrt{1-v^2}},\\
-\dfrac{v\, (3-2)}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}+\dfrac{2/299 792 458}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}-\dfrac{2/299 792 458}{\sqrt{1-v^2}},0,0{\huge ]}\\
={\huge [}\dfrac{(3-2)}{\sqrt{1-0.8660254^2}},-\dfrac{0.8660254\, (3-2)}{\sqrt{1-0.8660254^2}},0,0{\huge ]}\\
={\huge [}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-0.75}},-\dfrac{0.8660254}{\sqrt{1-0.75}},0,0{\huge ]}\\
={\huge [}\dfrac{1}{0.5},-\dfrac{0.8660254}{0.5},0,0{\huge ]}\\
={\huge [}2,-1.7320508,0,0{\huge ]}$
$\Delta {s_f'}^2=-c^2\Delta t^2+\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2+\Delta z^2\\=-2^2+(-1.7320508)^2+0^2+0^2=-4+3+0+0=-1$
Conclusion: The invariance of spacetime interval holds and all inertial observers agree there is no proper time delta between the head and the feet of a person.

I can't comment others answers because I have not built my reputation yet. @Dale there is no delta in proper time between the feet and the head in one's inertial frame.

but there is in other frames

No, there's is not. The invariance of spacetime interval does not allow it. There is simultaneity disagreement though.

The spacetime interval is invariant between two fixed events on a single worldline. Here we have two worldlines (head and foot) and the different frames choose different pairs of events. The invariance of the spacetime interval holds, but is not relevant to this point

We start in the rest frame. The foot proper time is 1s. The head proper time is 1s. This is how it is in the rest frame. How can we get different proper times in other moving frames if the invariance of spacetime interval holds?

"@kdp yes, please put your points in a question so we can get to the bottom of the seeming disagreement between you and Dale, since as things stand everyone else is left confused. Or, at least, I certainly am!" @Marco Ocram   Dale's calculations show simultaneity disagreement between inertial frames. The original question is not answered by that. The correct answer is there is no proper time difference between the feet and the head in the rest frame and because of the invariance of the spacetime interval every other moving intertial frame has to conclude the same result.

said “How can we get different proper times in other moving frames if the invariance of spacetime interval holds?” I both showed the math in my answer and explained the concept in my previous comment. You are incorrect on this point for the reasons I already provided.

@Dale you just showed there is a clock desynchronization. A sidenote $v L$ does not give you time units of measure. If you take your prime functions and calculate values for 3s, both h' and f' then calculate values for 2s. Now we do delta/spacetime interval h'(3)-h'(2)=f'(3)-f'(2)=1s because your "v L" in f' function cancels out.

Janoo said "you just showed there is a clock desynchronization". I also explained why that makes the invariance irrelevant. Specifically, I said "different frames choose different pairs of events". In units where $c=1$ then $vL$ does give you units of time.

@Dale Does $vL$ get cancelled when we calculate worldline spacetime interval as I showed? Is $h'(3)-h'(2)=f'(3)-f'(2)?

I am not sure why you are interested in that quantity (it isn't relevant to the question). But if you want it then you need to check your math. I gave all of the formulas $h'(3)-h'(2)=f'(3)-f'(2) = \left[ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2}},-\frac{v}{\sqrt{1-v^2}},0,0 \right] \ne 1$ Anyway, I am done. Your answer is factually wrong, the invariance of the spacetime interval does not imply that there is no proper time difference in different frames for the reasons already given multiple times

@Dale If you would continue your own calculation you get $[2,-1.7320508076,0,0]$ ... Squaring, adding $\Delta s^2=-1$. ... minus because it is time like spacetime interval. It's 1s. So $h'(3)-h'(2)$ is equal to $h(3)-h(2)$. Easy to show the same goes for feet.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Above for $v=0.866$.

This answer remains factually wrong even with the edit. The calculation is not relevant to the question. Note that $h'(3)=[6,-5.2,0,0]$ and $f'(3)=[-4.4,6.8,0,0]$. So the head is $3\mathrm{\ ns}$ old at $t'=6\mathrm{\ ns}$ and the foot is $3\mathrm{\ ns}$ old at $t'=-4.4 \mathrm{\ ns}$. ($c=1\mathrm{\ ft/ns}$, $v=0.866$, $L=6 \mathrm{\ ft}$) This is what is relevant to the question. There is an event where the age of the foot is 3 and an event where the age of the head is 3, but those events do not occur at the same time in the primed frame.

@Dale by comparing $h'(3)$ to $f'(3)$ you are calculating clock desynchronization between the head and the feet. To compare aging between the head and the feet, we need to calculate worldline spacetime inteverals along the head, the feet and this is done by comparing $h'(3)-h'(2)$, $f'(3)-f'(2)$. These two spacetime intervals are equal in any inertial reference frame.

Your calculation is not relevant to this question. Yes, those intervals are equal, but they do not address the question here (for the reasons already explained above)

@Dale Why primed simultaneity/clock desynchronization would change physical integrity of an object in the rest frame? As D. Halsey asked in his comment: "This is like asking if the laws of perspective make actual changes to the objects being observed." The delta of proper time is frame dependent even based on your equations. What frame is preferred? The conclusion has to be that the Lorentz transformation does not change physicality of an object in special relativity according to our current SR understanding.

Janooo said “Why primed simultaneity/clock desynchronization would change physical integrity of an object in the rest frame?” If you actually read my answer you would see that I said the opposite. I argue that the desynchronization (wherein the head and the feet have different ages in some frames) does not have any bearing on the characterization of a biological object in any frame.

@Dale You wrote:"The difference in age between the head and the foot can be no more..." There is no age delta between the head proper time and the foot proper time in the rest frame Your equation $\Delta \tau=...$ is pointless because it has no physical meaning, it does not represent proper time delta.

yes, as I already showed there is an age difference in any frame where they are moving. It is due to the clock de-synchronization (relativity of simultaneity) which you seem to recognize without understanding its consequences

It is incorrect to claim there is an age difference between the head and the feet based on an outside primed observer. This is mixing of inertial frames. The correct way is for any primed observer to do transformation back into the rest frame and to recognize there is no age delta in the rest frame.

Did you read your own comment, lol? First you complain about mixing frames and then you assert that the correct thing to do is to mix frames

What I am saying is that changing observers from one frame to another is supposed to be done through the transformation. Saying there is a delta between the head and the feet is mixing time between the frames without considering the transformation. The correct transformation resolves the simultaneity disagreement.

the question is exactly about the simultaneity difference. Using the reference frame of a moving observer, in that frame, according to the moving observer’s definition of time, is the head a different age than the foot? Yes. The simultaneity disagreement is a core feature of special relativity, not something that needs to be resolved.

Is there a real age delta between the feet and the head that challenges physical integrity of an object/body? Based on what frame?

There is a real age difference between the head and the feet in any frame where the body is moving. In what way exactly do you think a real age difference of 6 ns would affect the “physical integrity” of someone’s body?

6ns is only in one frame, other frames have different delta. Is the 6ns changing over time or it is constant in that one primed frame. If it is constant how it came to be this 6ns delta? What is this physical process that generated this 6ns delta?

Read my answer. All of those questions are answered with the math I derived. The 6 ns is a maximum in any frame, and in each frame whatever difference is constant.

What physical process makes/creates this delta between the feet and the head?

The Poincare symmetry of the laws of physics. Now you. In what way exactly do you think a real age difference of 6 ns would affect the “physical integrity” of someone’s body?

Acceleration is essential to physical processes. Imagine two observers in the rest frame K. Primed observer accelerates with K' reference system and reaches 0.1c velocity. K' stops acceleration and we are left with two inertial systems K and K' with 0.1c relative velocity. Lorentz transformation/boost does not capture information what frame accelerated. The time reversal symmetry is lost. The uniformly accelerated observer along x-axis will 'generate' clock desynchronization along x-axis, but when we are left with only K and K' frames then how do we know what frame accelerated?

You are avoiding my question. In what way exactly do you think a real age difference of 6 ns would affect the “physical integrity” of someone’s body?

I said multiple times, there is no 6ns delta. There is no real age difference. If I am in the rest frame K and I do not observer any difference then why would I believe a K' observer who tells me there is some difference? Seriously, why would K' frame overruled my K frame?

I quote you “Is there a real age delta between the feet and the head that challenges physical integrity of an object/body?” I said there is an age difference of <6ns. You say that “challenges physical integrity of an object/body”. So explain how you think that a <6ns age difference would challenge physical integrity. If you don’t think it would, then why did you add that in your question?

I said: "Is there a real age delta between the feet and the head that challenges physical integrity of an object/body? Based on what frame?" I am asking if there is any age delta that "might/would" challenge physical integrity, regardless if it is tiny or big then what frame determines that real age delta. My answer is that disagreement on simultaneity (clock desynchronization) does not affect the physical body, has no real physical effect on body(physical object), there is no age difference, based on our current understanding of the relativity.

And that juxtaposition of “age delta” and “challenges physical integrity” is disingenuous. Your question, as posed, does not represent either your belief nor mine. You are trying to artificially tie my demonstration of an age difference to a challenge to physical integrity that I explicitly rejected. There is an age difference that has no impact on object integrity.  And tying them together is unjustified by any of your arguments or mine

“My answer is that disagreement on simultaneity (clock desynchronization) does not affect the physical body” agreed “has no real physical effect on body(physical object),” correct “ there is no age difference,” incorrect. “based on our current understanding of the relativity” based on my well established correct understanding of relativity.

The rest frame does not have any age difference, but you say: "“ there is no age difference,” incorrect." Based on whose reference frame?

As clearly stated many times already in any reference frame where the body is moving.

According to Lorentz transformations (two cases: the moving observer approaches or moves away from the body ): $$\Delta x'=L'=\gamma(\Delta x\pm v\Delta t)=\gamma \Delta x \left(1\pm\frac{v}{c}\right)=\sqrt{\frac{1\pm\beta}{1\mp\beta}}\,L \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(*)$$
for $\;v/c=\beta <<1$ $$\Delta t'=(1\pm\beta)\Delta t= \Delta t \pm \beta \Delta t$$
we have for   $\Delta x=L\approx2m\;\;,\;\Delta t\approx L/c=6\, ns \;$, and  $v=10\,km/s$
$$\Delta t'- \Delta t= \pm 2. 10^{-13}s$$
for $\beta=0,9$ , with (*) (the observer approaches the body)  $$\Delta t'-\Delta t\approx -4,6\; ns $$ $$L'\approx 0,46\, m $$
he'll appear like a dwarf (so a human being).
or ( the observer moves away from the body)  $$\Delta t'-\Delta t \approx 20,16\, ns$$
$$L'\approx 8,7\, m $$
he can look through a 2nd floor window (a living being like a palm tree ).
